# Add Async Triggers into a Managed Package

Tags: trigger, change-data-capture, async-trigger

Salesforce released the [Process Change Event Messages in Apex Triggers](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_change_event_triggers.htm) in Summer '19, is this feature available in the managed package?

Comment: Not definitive, but during the London Salesforce Partner Forum (targeted at Partners creating managed packages and other AppExchange offerings) they went into detail on these technologies. I would, therefore, think the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this feature is available for managed package .

In order to test this i created a simple package with the below code

Trigger code

---

```
trigger AccountChangeAsyncTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
List<AccountChangeEvent> changes = Trigger.new;

Set<String> accIds = new Set<String>();
List<Contact> lstcontacts = new List<Contact>();

//Get all record Ids for this change and add it to a set for further processing
for(AccountChangeEvent acc: changes){
    List<String> recordIds = acc.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds();
    accIds.addAll(recordIds);
}

for(Id accId: accIds) {
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.LastName = 'Test';
    c.AccountId = accId;
    lstcontacts.add(c);
}

   insert lstcontacts;
}
```

---

Test Code

---

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountChangeAsyncTrigger {
@isTest
static  void testAsyncContactCreate() { 
    // Enable all Change Data Capture entities for notifications.
    Test.enableChangeDataCapture();

    Test.startTest();
    // Insert an account to generate a change event.
    insert new Account(Name='TestAccount', Phone='4155551212');
    Test.stopTest();
    // The stopTest() call fires the trigger with the test account change event.

    // VERIFICATIONS
    // Check that the change event trigger created a task.
    Contact[] contactList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];        
    System.assertEquals(1, contactList.size(),
        'The change event trigger did not create the expected contact.');
   }
}
```

Created a managed package and installed the package in another environment and everything worked as expected .

NOTE: You will need to enable change data capture for the object on which you want this feature .

For custom objects include the custom object in the package that will also include the async trigger as a part of dependency .

FYI

---

In case you are following the comments there is alternate way to write tests for this

```
@isTest
public class TestAccountChangeAsyncTrigger {
@isTest
static  void testAsyncContactCreate() { 

    Test.startTest();

    // Insert an account to generate a change event.
    insert new Account(Name='TestAccount', Phone='4155551212');
    // Enable all Change Data Capture entities for notifications.
    Test.getEventBus().deliver();

    Test.stopTest();
    // The stopTest() call fires the trigger with the test account change event.

    // VERIFICATIONS
    // Check that the change event trigger created a task.
    Contact[] contactList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];        
    System.assertEquals(1, contactList.size(),
        'The change event trigger did not create the expected contact.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Outta curiosity what happens when you call `Test.getEventBus().deliver();` ?

Comment: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: The change event trigger did not create the expected contact.: Expected: 1, Actual: 0

Comment: +1. Interesting, how would I test async trigger is working

Comment: You mean in test class or org ?

Comment: I mean, I can change record , it will fire async change triggers, If I wanna unit test that how can I? as `Test.getEventBus().deliver();` is not workin

Comment: Using Test.enableChangeDataCapture() .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95685/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-pranay-jaiswal).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Which metadata type to choose when you add the Asyn Trigger to the managed package? I wrote a test one, but can not select it.

Comment: Trigger and apex metadata

Comment: I tried in my org. I found a standard object asyn trigger is listed, but my custom object asyn trigger does not be listed in the Apex Trigger.  @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Have not tried for custom object yet .Check under platform event channel or something along those lines

Comment: I tried all options that can not find it.

Comment: Wow !! That's bad .I will try tomorrow morning with custom object as well and see if I can replicate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95701/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-jair).

Comment: Did you try a custom object? @MohithShrivastava

Comment: @jair yes it works .All you need is add the custom object to package and trigger gets auto added .